# SQL Server Bulk Insert Skip Primary Key Violations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm currently using SQL Server's Native [Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) procedure to load several tables into a database from text files.

This has been working well and even handles truncation,null,and formatting errors gracefully. If any column is too large, is null when it shouldn't be, or if there is an incorrect number of columns found based on the format file, those rows are skipped and forwarded to an error file.

Recently however, a duplicate primary key was entered into one of my text files. This caused the bulk insert to simply fail, no row was forwarded to the error file.

Currently my bulk insert commands look like this:

```
BULK INSERT table.table FROM 'data_file.txt' WITH(
    BATCHSIZE = 100000,
    CODEPAGE = 1252,
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    KEEPNULLS,
    MAXERRORS = 1000000000,
    TABLOCK,
    FORMATFILE = 'format_file.txt',
    ERRORFILE = 'error_file.txt'
)
```

Is there a way, using bulk insert, to handle primary key violations the same way other errors are handled? Ideally I would like rows containing PK violations forwarded to the same error file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly answer your question, **no**.

> UNIQUE, and PRIMARY KEY constraints are **always enforced**. When importing into a character column that is defined with a NOT NULL constraint, BULK INSERT inserts a blank string when there is no value in the text file.

I would recommend using a staging or temp table for your bulk insert and move it from there to the actual tables.

[`BULK INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) without the `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` option also has other ramifications for your table:

> CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
>
> Specifies that all constraints on the target table or view must be checked during the bulk-import operation. Without the CHECK_CONSTRAINTS option, any CHECK and FOREIGN KEY constraints are ignored, and **after the operation, the constraint on the table is marked as not-trusted.**

Which can **[negatively impact performance](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo%5Fkornelis/archive/2007/03/29/can-you-trust-your-constraints.aspx)** of queries if you don't **[fix it](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/)** after.

Comment: I had seen that quote in the MSDN document, but wasn't sure if there was a unique way around it. I hadn't seen anyone ask this question directly, so hopefully this can help others in the future if they find themselves in the same scenario.

Check constraints is something I planned to enable, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, and there are other ways to achieve the same goal, just not with `BULK INSERT` as far as I am aware. Good luck @NightTrain!

Comment: There is no circumstance where I would import data directly to a production table in any event.  We not only use one staging tables, we use two. One with all the data as it came in from the file and one for the transformed data that will go to prod. This makes researching questions that arise from data imports much easier (we can know in just one query if the troublesome data  came from our transformation or came in from the client that way) especially when you have multi-million row files that you can't just easily open and search.

Comment: I definitely agree with you. The tables I am inserting into are in fact meant to be the data as it came in from the file, pre-transform. I'm attempting to filter bad rows on the fly so they can be reported to the file provider quickly.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd just drop the primary key from the table and have a query that checks for duplicates in addition to using the error file to find issues with the data. @NightTrain

Comment: That's the current plan of action. Thanks guys. @SqlZim